# Does log-transforming a slightly-skewed y variable make any sense?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, logarithm

I'm separately analyzing 5 subsets of my data and running multiple linear regressions with the same outcome variable in each. (I am also running a single regression with all the subsets and using the subset variable as a predictor, but it is useful to run separate regressions for each subset because the results are quite different for each subset, in ways you would not be able to tell from the overall regression.)

The outcome variable is continuous and, prior to the log-transformation, I was modeling it in its original form. It is usually positive but in some cases zero (for that reason, I add a constant when log-transforming it.)

The variable is highly skewed in 4 subsets so I'm log-transforming it with a constant, chosen separately for each subset to lower the skewness of the variable in that subset to acceptable levels.

The thing is, the variable in the 5th subset is only slightly skewed (.28), well within the acceptable range. However, if I have a single table illustrating all 5 regressions, it's going to be hard for any reader to compare the magnitude of coefficients across the different subsets if 4 of the subsets have a logged y variable and one of them doesn't.

So my question is, does it make any sense to log-transform the y variable for the slightly skewed subset too? Would this make the results more accurate?

I tried doing so, adding a constant to reduce the skewness all the way to .006. When I run the regression with the log-transformed y variable, the results are mainly the same, but now two additional x variables have statistically significant effects. So it really does change the overall results.

On the one hand, presenting my results this way would be easier to interpret for the reader, and now the outcome variable is utterly devoid of skewness. But on the other hand, it wasn't necessary to log-transform that y variable for that subset. Is there a risk I actually made my results less accurate? Is there any other reason why this is a bad idea?

Comment: Why would skewness of a variable indicate you need to transform it?

Comment: In my field it is conventional to log-transform this particular y variable whenever it has skew greater than 1, which is most of the time. The idea is that the regression is more accurate or valid that way...

Comment: Hi Wisconsinite and welcome to CV! It would be nice to know the underlying reason for this being a common practice in your field. If that reason is related to the "normality" of your dependent variable (DV = Y), then it is likely not a good reason as "normality" of your DV is not an assumption of a linear regression models (if that is what you are modelling Y with).

Comment: In addition to saying why you need to correct skewness in the outcome variable, please edit the question to say why you are modeling your data as 5 different subsets with the same outcome variable. A single model of all the data that incorporates the "subset" as a predictor in some way would seem to be a preferred and much more efficient use of data.

Comment: Fanfoue: This is the reason, but as I understand it, the normality of the residuals is the problem that calls for log-transformation. I checked, and it seems that in practice when the y variable is not normally distributed neither are the residuals... In my case, for the other ones I am transforming, the residuals of the model are not normal unless I log-transform the y variable.

Comment: EdM: Thanks. Done.

Comment: What's the nature of the outcome variable? Is it continuous, or is it something discrete like counts? Are you modeling it in its original form, or as a ratio or percentage or other transformation? Is it necessarily non-negative, or even necessarily positive? Again, please add that information by editing the question.

Comment: EdM: Done, thanks.

Comment: Seeing the data and learning more about the nature of the outcome variable really would help. (It's rare that either is utterly irrelevant.) Other possibilities include a generalized linear model with log link,  which doesn't require that all values are positive, only that the mean outcome is, conditional on predictors. I agree that different transformations for different subsets are hard (dogmatically: impossible) to justify and that minimising skewness is not a major goal compared with getting the dependence of the outcome on the predictors well approximated.

Comment: @Wisconsinite "it seems that in practice when the y variable is not normally distributed neither are the residuals.." --- while it can happen, this is not necessarily the case. Since it *doesn't* follow that a skewed marginal distribution implies a similarly skewed conditional distribution (indeed it's easy to flip the direction of the skewness from one to the other), it would instead be better to think about the variables themselves - you can often infer likely skewness from things like what you're measuring, for example, from prior studies of the same variables, from pilot samples, ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... from theory, from expert knowledge, etc, to identify a model. You would still check that such assumptions were reasonable post hoc, but it would only be necessary to worry where the impact of such violations on the properties of the inference were likely to be substantial (e.g. you can't then get a second bite at the model without impacting its properties). If you must use the same sample to choose the model and perform inference, it's better to set it up so that the selection (including of transformations) and inference don't use the same data points

Answer (score 1):

A separate model for each subset, each with a separate transformation of the same outcome variable, isn't a good approach. Your worry

> ...if I have a single table illustrating all 5 regressions, it's going to be hard for any reader to compare the magnitude of coefficients across the different subsets if 4 of the subsets have a logged y variable and one of them doesn't

holds even "with a constant, chosen separately for each subset" added prior to log transformation. A regression coefficient associated with an outcome of $\log(y+1)$ isn't on the same scale as one associated with an outcome of $\log(y+10)$.

The "results ... quite different for each subset" can be handled by going beyond a simple coefficient for `subset` to include interactions between other predictors and `subset`. In a single combined model you could examine the overall distribution of residuals and then decide how to proceed. As you note, it's the distribution of residuals that matters, not that of the original y values.

If you want to go the y-transformation route, choose a common transformation that provides an acceptable overall distribution in the combined model. That could be a single choice of constant prior to log transformation. Or it could be a different type of transformation entirely, like a square root transformation. You don't have to end up with an exactly normal distribution of residuals; they just have to be well enough behaved. You can also get robust estimators of coefficient (co)variances that can handle deviations from the simplest linear regression assumptions.

Perhaps better, avoid y-transformation entirely. Continuous outcomes can be modeled with ordinal regression. A proportional-odds model is an extension of standard non-parametric tests to regression models. Frank Harrell explains this in Chapter 13 of his [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/), and provides an `orm()` function in his [`rms` package](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) that's designed to handle continuous outcomes efficiently.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I am probably doing it wrong (I am in the process of learning this kind of thing on my own), but when I do what I think you're suggesting, creating a single interactive model using the interaction of factor(subset variable)*factor(ordinal predictor variable), then my results are completely different from what I obtain through doing separate regressions for each subset, which seems impossible. Beyond the technical issue of whether I'm doing this right, I don't understand how it can be wrong to separate the data into subsets since each are legitimate regressions...

Comment: @Wisconsinite separate-subset analysis isn't necessarily wrong, but it's usually much less powerful. If you are getting apparently "completely different" results between that and a full-interaction model, there might be a problem with interpreting interaction-model results. With interactions, individual coefficients represent _differences_ from the Intercept under baseline conditions, and the interaction coefficients are _extra differences_ associated with combinations of interacting predictors. Try posting a new question with results from both approaches, asking why they seem to differ.